# Importing keychain to mac through command line from existing keychain file

Tags: macos, shell, jenkins, xamarin

I'm working on getting a Jenkins build process set up for a Xamarin IOS project I have.  I've set up the Jenkins configuration so that a Keychain file is uploaded to the Jenkins configuration and put on the build server to execute the build/signing of the application.

So I have the keychain file on the build server at the time the build is executing.  However, i'm having issues opening that Keychain file to install it on the machine so that my app can then be signed with the appropriate certificates.

I was able to get it working on my local Jenkins instance, but have run into problems with the Jenkins server I am using.

My shell command that the Jenkins configuration executes is:

```
open "path to my keychain here"
security unlock-keychain -p "my installed keychain"
"rest of build"
```

On the build server, the open command is failing with this error:

LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application "app name" with error -10810

I've searched around a bit but haven't been able to find the -10810 error code.  I've seen others, but not this same error code.  Any idea how to get around this error code, or is there any other way for me to install a keychain from my keychain file without using the Open command?

The reason we are doing it this way is that we do not want the certs added to the build machines keychain by default.  We are trying to have the Jenkins Configurations install and remove the keychains they use for their builds during their execution.

Thanks for all help

Comment: Perhaps the answer to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181026/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-cant-open-install-os-x-yosemite) will help understand the error code.

Answer (score 0):

open -a 'Keychain Access' "path to my keychain here"

or you can set the search list to your keychain:

security list-keychains -s "path to my keychain here"